# How to remove partricules and apostrophes in url

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I'm using drupal 8 and Pathauto.

I have title of the type (in French) `Personnes d'Allemagne`, I would like to delete `d'` to have like url `personnes-allemagne`.

Pathauto removes the apostrophes well, but preserves the particle before, which gives `people-dallemagne`.

I tried to add in the words to delete `d'` or just `d`, but it does not work. Pathauto continues to delete only the apostrophe and not the `d`.

I thought of replacing the apostrophe with a dash, but I would prefer to delete particle and dash.

Someone has a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been able to achieve it with the Pathauto module 8.x-1.3, using the following settings (/admin/config/search/path/settings).

- For *Strings to Remove* I used *a, an, as, at, before, but, by, for, from, is, in, into, like, of, off, on, onto, per, since, than, the, this, that, to, up, via, with, d'*
- Under *Punctuation*, for *Single quotation marks (apostrophe) (')*, I selected *No action (do not replace)*

I used */content/[node:nid]/[node:title]* as pattern for the nodes, and created a node with *Personnes d'Allemagne* as title. The path alias for that node has been set to /content/1/personnes-allemagne.

> [image: screenshot]

The disadvantage is that the apostrophe will not taken off from the path aliases, except when it is present in a string given for the *Strings to Remove* setting.

Answer (score 2):

The punctuation processing is done before the words processing/replacements and Kiamlaluno's answer would be my solution too.

Just wanted to point out that if you want to **reenable the apostrophe stripping** but still keep the `d'` stripping you can do so in a custom module

```
function MODULENAME_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, array &$context) {
  $alias = str_replace("'","",$alias);
}
```

Comment: Thank for that! I had the same use case and this worked fine.